# При выгрузке на хостинг, на сайте вместо русских символов отображаются?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Пробовал на локальном сервере, все работало прекрасно
В папку с файлом добавлен файл .htaccess добавил текст AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
В свое время это помогло на локалке(правда там были не вопросы, а кракозябры.
В таблице кодировка utf-8 general_ci. [image: База данных в кодировке ютф8[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpDCg.png)
[[image: Данные таблицы в кодировке utf-8]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUyeR.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>PHP searching</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','u0584147_admin','admin123','u0584147_admindb') or die ("Error");
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM phptesttable");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) echo "<h1>".$row['name']."</h1><p>".$row['manufacturer']."<br>".$row['description']."</p><br>";
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search" class="search">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="поиск">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $search = explode (" ",$_POST['search']);
                $count = count($search);
                $array = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach($search as $key){
                    $i++;
                    if ($i < $count) $array[] = "CONCAT (`name`,`manufacturer`) LIKE '%".$key."%' OR "; else $array[] = "CONCAT (`name`,`manufacturer`) LIKE '%".$key."%'";
                }
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM phptesttable WHERE ".implode("",$array);
                echo $sql;
                $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                //$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM phptesttable WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `manufacturer` LIKE '%$search%' ");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) echo "<h1>".$row['name']."</h1><p>".$row['manufacturer']."<br>".$row['description']."</p><br>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8")` ?

Comment: Ничего не изменилось(

Answer (score -1):

есть несколько возможних вариантов

1. в самих html файлах

Пример:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
```

2. в файле ".htaccess" файле в конкретном каталоге.

Пример:

```
DefaultLanguage ru

AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```

3. в разделе "Настройка РНР", админпанели хостинга
4. в импортируемом на MYSQL сервер дампе базы данных
5. в настройках скриптов Вашего сайта.

Пример:

```
<?php

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);

mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");

"?>
```